# Google popup Espresso Android studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, android-espresso

How to handle a click on the button `com.google.android.gms:id/cancel` (text "None of the above") for a Google dialog as in the screenshot attached with Espresso UI Testing?
[[image: \Sign in screenshot]]

Comment: Is it necessary to open and click this dialog? If not Espresso can catch intents and provide stubbed answers. https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/

Answer (score 4):

These account chooser dialogs are out of your test application scope. Espresso cannot handle these UI elements.

You can use `uiautomator` as part of you `Espresso` tests.

See example below

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SocialLoginTest {
private UiDevice mUiDevice;

@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    mUiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
}

@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception {
    //Launch activity
    //Simulate a Click on the button in your activity that triggers account chooser dialog.

    UiObject mText = mUiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("NONE OF THE ABOVE"));
    mText.click();
    //Assertions for results handled in your application
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it and reply back with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [withText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#withText(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

```
onView(withText("None of the above")).perform(click());
```

I made a example in [GitHub](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/DialogEspresso/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/thedeveloperworldisyours/dialogespresso/MainActivityTest.java),
If you need more clarification, please tell me.

Comment: This is not working with espresso library: onView(withId(android.R.id.cancel)).perform(click());

Comment: You can use [withText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#withText(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that in that case `Espresso` may not work properly due this framework limitation.  Try to achieve it using Google's typical instrumentation tool called `uiautomator`. It works great along with `Espresso`.

Check: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

You can also try to use open-source UI automation tool called `Robotium` along with `Espresso`.

Check: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/UI-Testing-with-Robotium

Using only `Espresso` you are allowed to operate only inside your app under test context, so you cannot check notifications, most of popup dialogs or running another app from exisitng and cheking both.

Hope it will help